# How to limit how much storage is a Kubernetes managed Docker container allowed?

Tags: kubernetes

I am familiar with Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/limit-storage-consumption/) that describes how to setup limits for PVC. However, what if the container is not assigned PVC?

Suppose a Kubernetes container that simply defines:

```
- image: 'redis:7'
  name: redis
```

... I keep writing data to this Redis instance.

- How do I set a quota to ensure that the container does not use more than allocated storage?
- How to inspect how much storage is already used?

I have tried setting `ResourceQuota` for ephemeral resources such as:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  labels:
  # {{ include "app.resource_labels" . | indent 4 }}
  name: '{{ .Release.Name }}'
spec:
  hard:
    configmaps: 10
    limits.cpu: 4
    limits.ephemeral-storage: 1Gi
    limits.memory: 10Gi
    pods: 30
    secrets: 5
    services: 20
```

However, when inspecting quota, it always says 0 for `ephemeral-storage`.

```
kubectl describe quota
Name:                     gaia-review-contra-resource-quota-c79e5b3c
Namespace:                gaia-review-c79e5b3c
Resource                  Used     Hard
--------                  ----     ----
configmaps                2        10
limits.cpu                21       4
limits.ephemeral-storage  0        1Gi
limits.memory             25576Mi  10Gi
pods                      16       30
secrets                   4        5
services                  8        20
```

Therefore, I suspect that something else is not working as it should or I am looking at the wrong place.

Meanwhile, the VMs that are running these pods is experiencing disk pressure.

[image: VMs]

[image]

[image]

My next best theory is that it is actually the Docker image layers that are filling the disk space, but I am unsure how to confirm that or why resources are not being freed.

Comment: Have you read through the documentation on [resource quotas](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/)? Look in particular for "ephemeral storage".

Answer (score 1):

If the container is not assigned to PVC then assuming ephemeral storage is assigned will be used by default.

To ensure that the container does not use more than allocated storage set the **`memory limits field spec.containers[].resources.limits.memory`**.

Below example is taken from this [official kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#local-ephemeral-storage) doc, similarly you can also set limits to your containers.

```
containers:

 - name: log-aggregator

   image: images.my-company.example/log-aggregator:v6

   resources:

     requests:

       ephemeral-storage: "2Gi"

     limits:

       ephemeral-storage: "4Gi"
```

As @larks suggested, this document contains a detailed explanation and more methods which will help you and you can also use [resource quotas](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/#resource-quota-per-priorityclass) for storage to set limits.

For more information  you can also refer to the [Resource Management for Pods and Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#example-1) doc.

Comment: I wonder if something else is going on here. I already have namespace `ResourceQuota` configured. However, when I look at `kubectl describe quota`, it says that used ephemeral-storage is 0. And that just cannot be true.

Comment: Use `docker system df` and `docker ps --size` to check the sizes of the containers and resources. see which is taking up the space. use `docker system prune` that will clean up any resources — images, containers, volumes, and networks — that are dangling (not tagged or associated with a container):